# Overlapping sections in PE format

Tags: portable-executable

I want to write a loader for the PE format. One [binary](https://github.com/rfalke/decompiler-subjects/blob/5afd1adcae832bb3a8306d46e92eb77c60a3d24c/malware_via_email/malware_1171/ia32_pe/subject.exe) contains two sections which overlap in the virtual address space.

```
     5 sections:
            name     virtual-size    | virtual-address | sizeOfRawData   | ptrToRawData    | characteristics                 
       [ 0] ".text"  0x00116e/  4462 | 0x001000/  4096 | 0x001200/  4608 | 0x000400/  1024 | 0x60000020 R-X CODE             
       [ 1] ".rdata" 0x000e42/  3650 | 0x003000/ 12288 | 0x001000/  4096 | 0x001600/  5632 | 0x40000040 R-- IDATA            
       [ 2] ".data"  0x015011/ 86033 | 0x004000/ 16384 | 0x005200/ 20992 | 0x002600/  9728 | 0xc0000040 RW- IDATA            
       [ 3] ".rsrc"  0x003000/ 12288 | 0x01a000/106496 | 0x002800/ 10240 | 0x007800/ 30720 | 0x40000040 R-- IDATA            
       [ 4] ".reloc" 0x000474/  1140 | 0x01b000/110592 | 0x000000/     0 | 0x007c00/ 31744 | 0x50000000 R-- MEM_SHARED
```

Here `.rsrc` has the range 0x01a000-0x01d000 and `.reloc` the range 0x01b000-0x01b474 which is a clear overlap.

Questions:

1. Is there something special with this binary so that the sections do not overlap?
2. Since the [spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) doesn't say anything about overlap: is such a binary valid for Windows?
3. Which section controls the actual content of bytes in the range 0x01b000-0x01b474?
4. What characteristics does the range 0x01b000-0x01b474 have?